# jQuery how to slow result in post function

Tags: jquery, post

I have a function that load data in a form but I noted that data are correctly returned by PHP page, I can see them on firebug but form fields are not filled. I've tried for debug to put an alert inside my function and I noted that after alert confirmation data are filled. So is there a way to slow filling?

Here is my code:

```
$.post("./php/"+eti[indice]+".php", //here post data to populate html page loaded
    {azione: "carica", contratto:contratto},
    function(xml)
    {
        if ($("sessione", xml).text()=="1")
        {
            if ($("status", xml).text()=="1")
            {
                alert("qua ci arrivo!");
                var lungh=Number(schemi.length)-1;
                if (indice==lungh)
                {
                    $("#ui-tabs-"+ind).append("<div style='clear:both'><div style='float:right' id='new_def_fine'><div id='"+eti[indice]+"_"+indice+"' class='bt'>FINE</div></div></div>");
                }
                else
                {
                    var indice2 = Number(indice) + 1;
                    $("#ui-tabs-"+ind).append("<div style='clear:both'><div style='float:right' id='new_def'><div id='"+eti[indice]+"_"+indice2 +"' class='bt'>>></div></div></div>");
                }
                scorriDati(xml, "form_"+schemi[indice]);
            }
            else
            {
                $(xml).find("errore").each(function()
                {
                    $("#ris_dial").append("<span style='color:red'>"+$(this).text()+"<br></span>\n");
                });
                $("#ris_dial").dialog(dialogError);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            window.location.href="index.html";
        }
    },'xml'
);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're filling in any form fields...

Comment: Are you calling the post function in document ready event?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry, I use scorriDati function but that's work I use it in other pages without problem..

Comment: @Cybernate: I use: $(function(){ ... });

Answer (score 1):

I've noted that if I simultaneously load a form page and with $.post() I fill in form data often happen that field remain empty.

I resolved simply put $.post in a delay function.